# SQL Server joins two columns both ID of a table with another table's primary Key Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is an easy way of joining these two tables.

Table "**Table1**":

| Name | FromCountryID | ToCountryID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sam | 1 | 2 |
| lee | 3 | 4 |
| john | 2 | 1 |
| marc | null | 3 |

Table "**Table2**":

| CountryID | CountryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | UK |
| 3 | Canada |
| 4 | Nepal |

```
select t1.name, 
       fromTab.countryName as FromCountry,
       toTab.countryName as ToCountry
from table1 t1
left join table2 fromTab on fromTab.countryId = t1.fromCountryId
left join table2 toTab on toTab.countryId = t1.toCountryId
```

Comment: You seem to be using an easy way to join them

Comment: The only thing you can do to make it faster, is to use indices, otherwise this looks like the best way to address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

please try this :

```
select t1.Name,t2.CountryName as FromCountry,t3.CountryName as ToCountry from [dbo].[Table1] t1
left join [dbo].[Table2] t2
on(t1.FromCountryID=t2.CountryID)
left join [dbo].[Table2] t3
on(t1.ToCountryID=t3.CountryID)
```

[image]

or

```
select t1.Name,t1.FromCountryID,t2.CountryName as FromCountry,t1.ToCountryID,t3.CountryName as ToCountry from [dbo].[Table1] t1
left join [dbo].[Table2] t2
on(t1.FromCountryID=t2.CountryID)
left join [dbo].[Table2] t3
on(t1.ToCountryID=t3.CountryID)
```

[image]